# Convert system.collection.generic.list to list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am using linq code parsing XML file.This is my code. I want bind detail and image are list.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notchs));
      XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);
      Notchs notchs = (Notchs)serializer.Deserialize(xmlDoc.CreateReader());

      var query = from l in xmlDoc.Descendants("Category")
            select new Notch
            {
               name = (string)l.Attribute("name").Value,
               Titles = l.Element("Articles").Elements("article")
                         .Select(s => s.Attribute("title").ToString())
                         .ToList(),

               Image = l.Element("Articles").Elements("article").Elements("thumb_image").Elements("image")
                        .Select(x => x.Attribute("url").ToString()).ToList()
            };

      foreach (var result in query)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(result.name);
          foreach (var detail in result.Titles)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(detail);
          }
      }

      NotchsList.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

I tried this code but i got the output like below ..but I want the details and images are list.

```
  name

  System.Collection.Generic.List'1[string.system]

  name

  System.Collection.Generic.List'1[string.system]
```

Comment: Please give us some sample data (XML) and how your output should look like.

Comment: @user123: in the future please edit your question instead of posting a new one. If you don't know how to edit read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
Titles = l.Element("Articles").Elements("article")
                                   .Select(s => s.Attribute("title").ToString())
                                   .ToList()
```

is returning an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>>`.  You may want to do a `.SelectMany` instead of `.Select`.

Comment: i tried this thing i got Error like Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'